# How can I get the name of the macro-function?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have the macro:

```
#define MYMACRO(pred, ...) \
    pred /* here 'pred' is 'mypred(1, 2)', but I need to get only the name without args */
```

Which is used like this:

```
MYMACRO(mypred(1, 2))
```

I need to get only the name of the macro-function, without arguments.

I can do it like this:

```
#define mypred(...) \
    mypred
#define MYMACRO_EXPAND(pred) \
    pred /* here 'pred' is 'mypred' without args */
#define MYMACRO(pred, ...) \
    MYMACRO_EXPAND(pred)
```

But this way is bad because I should define the macros for all possible macro-functions.
Ideas?

Comment: This sounds like an XY question. What is it you are ACTUALLY trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, but i do not recommend.
For example print the function name.

```
#define MYMACRO(func, ...) \
   (printf("%s\n", #func), func(__VA_ARGS__))
```

And use it this way

```
MYMACRO(mypred, 1, 2);
```

or

```
int a = MYMACRO(pred, 1, 2);
```